# Is this a correct way of writing a BDD Test Scenario?

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd

Can i split a BDD Test Scenario in two:

Requirement:

If the booking is a , and the  is not eligible for check-in, then display the following message: ‘ Success, 
Once Ok is selected display BP.

Test Scenario:

Background:

GIVEN I have selected check in
    AND I am online

Scenario Outline: ***** - Return Flight is NOT eligible for BP page

```
   GIVEN I am on the 'D' Page
   WHEN i select the  'YES' selection tab
   THEN  the following  message is displayed ‘ Success, <Pax Name> '

    GIVEN i have selected 'YES' on the D Page
    WHEN i select 'OK' on the displayed message
    THEN the BP page is displayed
```

Also:

Requirement:

Include a selection tab of Yes & No to allow user to confirm that they are the passenger. (Default highlighted to Yes)
a. Yes – if selected will xxxxx
b. No – if selected will return user to aaaaaaaaa

Background:

GIVEN I have selected check in
  AND I am online

GIVEN I am on the 'D' Page
THEN the page should have a  'Yes' & 'No' selection tab
AND the 'YES' selection tab  is highlighted

GIVEN I am on the 'D' Page
WHEN I select the 'NO' selection tab
THEN i'm returned to the check in page

Answer (score 0):

You can always mix and match steps.
For example, the first Scenario could be done as follows:

```
Scenario: Return Flight is NOT eligible for BP page
   GIVEN I am on the 'D' Page
   WHEN i select the  'YES' selection tab
   THEN  the following  message is displayed ‘ Success, <Pax Name> '
   WHEN i select 'OK' on the displayed message
   THEN the BP page is displayed
```